# error local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that rounds each number in a list to the closest number out of this list of numbers (-3,0,2,4,7,10,12). When I try to run the following code, python gives me this error message: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'GR' referenced before assignment". Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

```py
def roundGrade(grades):
    grades = []

    for i in grades:
        if (grades >= 11) and (grades <= 12):
            gradesRounded == 12
        elif (grades >= 8.5) and (grades < 11):
            gradesRounded == 10
        elif (grades >= 5.5) and (grades < 8.5):
            gradesRounded == 7
        elif (grades >= 3) and (grades < 5.5):
            gradesRounded == 4
        elif (grades >= 1) and (grades < 3):
            gradesRounded == 2
        elif (grades >= -1.5) and (grades < 1):
            gradesRounded == 0
        elif (grades >= -3) and (grades < -1.5):
            gradesRounded = -3
        else:
            print("Grade out of range")

    return gradesRounded

print(roundGrade([8.2, -0.5, 10.4, 5.7]))
```

Comment: There is no variable named `GR`... Also `gradesRounded` is assigned inside the `for` loop, but never initialized outside the `for` loop (yet it is used in `return` statement outside the `for` loop)

Comment: there is no variable called `GR` in your code.

Comment: Its `gradesRounded` Variable. It is not initialized. Also, you are accepting grades as input and assigning it to blank list  in the statement `grades = []`

Comment: you never set gradesRounded variable cause your loop never runs, because you create an empty list called grades.

Comment: You also have a typo in the firsts if you write gradesRounded==n (compare to instead of assign)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code. Your function is passed a parameter called `grades`, which in you case is a list. You then immediately overwrite `grades` with an empty list. The `for` loop tries to iterate over elements in an empty list so your loop never runs. You then try to return `gradesRounded` which has never been set.

If you did manage to iterate the loop there are several issues here. You are comparing the variable `grades` (which is a list) to an integer. This will not work. You should be comparing `i` which would be updated on each loop to point to the next value in the `grades` list.

You are also comparing gradesRounded with an integer by using the double equals `==`. If you want to assign to it then you need to use the single equals. On top of that, you are overwriting the value of gradesRounded every time. If you ever managed to `return gradesRounded` it would contain only a single integer which would be the last grade it rounded.

I have to make some assumptions here that you want to pass in a list of grades and be returned a list of equivalent rounded grades. Below is an updated version of your code that does just that.

```
def round_grades(grades):
    rounded_grades = []
    for grade in grades:
        if 11 <= grade <= 12:
            rounded_grades.append(12)
        elif 8.5 <= grade < 11:
            rounded_grades.append(10)
        elif 5.5 <= grade < 8.5:
            rounded_grades.append(7)
        elif 3 <= grade < 5.5:
            rounded_grades.append(4)
        elif 1 <= grade < 3:
            rounded_grades.append(2)
        elif -1.5 <= grade < 1:
            rounded_grades.append(0)
        elif -3 <= grade < -1.5:
            rounded_grades.append(-3)
        else:
            print("Grade out of range")

    return rounded_grades

print(round_grades([8.2, -0.5, 10.4, 5.7]))
```

INPUT: `[8.2, -0.5, 10.4, 5.7]`

OUTPUT: `[7, 0, 10, 7]`

Answer (score 0):

First it looks like you are not actually comparing each individual grade in grades but actually the list itself.

For example one of your lines should look like

```
for i in grades:
    if (i >= 11) and (i <= 12):
        gradesRounded = 12
    elif (i >= 8.5) and (i < 11):
        gradesRounded = 10
```

Your main problem though is that you are using double equal signs  to assign a value to gradesRounded which just checks if they are equal (returning true or false). You need just a single equal sign. I have changed this in the changed code above.

Comment: thanks :) I have changed my code to the same format as you typed and removed the empty list. But now it only rounds the last coordinate of the list and not the others... How can we fix that?

Comment: are you sure this does what is needed. every time you iterate through the grades list, you will over write the value of gradesRounded. So when you return gradesRounded it wont be a match list of rounded grades that you passed in. It will be the integer value of the list rounded grade only.

Comment: @Nemo I have provided an answer with full code example that will return a rounded list

Answer (score 0):

```
def roundGrade(grades):
    grades = []

    for i in grades:
        ...
    return gradesRounded
```

problem is line `grades = []`. It creates a new list which is empty, so now when you try to iterate  `for i in grades:`, `grades` is an empty list, it is not the same list you passed to this function: `roundGrade(grades):`